# Mellin transform of $(1-x)^k 1_{[0,1]}(x) e(\alpha x)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, integral-transforms

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} (1-x)^k e(\alpha x) &\text{for $0\leq x\leq 1$}\\ 0&\text{for $x>1$,}\end{cases}$$ where $e(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$ and $k\geq 0$. Let us consider its Mellin transform $\mathscr{M}f = \int_0^\infty f(x) x^{s-1} dx$. (This is a question that arises naturally when one studies exponential sums with a very simple polynomial smoothing.)

Integrating by parts $\ell$ times, and noting that (for $\Delta g(s) = g(s+1)-g(s)$) $$(-\Delta)^k \frac{1}{s (s+1) \dotsc (s+n)} = 
(-\Delta)^{k-1} \frac{(n+1)}{s (s+1)\dotsc (s+n+1)} = \frac{(n+1)\dotsb (n+k)}{s (s+1) \dotsc (s+n+k)}$$for $n\geq 0$, we see that, for $\ell\geq 1$,
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{M} f(s) &= \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j \binom{k}{j}  \frac{e(\alpha)}{s+j} - 
    \sum_{j=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^j \binom{k}{j} \cdot 2\pi i \alpha}{s+j}
    \int_0^1 x^{s+j} e(\alpha x) dx\\
    &= \frac{k!\cdot e(\alpha)}{s (s+1) \dotsb (s+k)} -
    \frac{(k+1)!\cdot (2\pi i \alpha) e(\alpha)}{s (s+1) \dotsb (s+k+1)} + \sum_{j=0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^j \binom{k}{j} (2\pi i \alpha)^2}{(s+j) (s+j+1)} \int_0^1 x^{s+j+1} e(\alpha x) dx\\
    &= \frac{k! e(\alpha)}{s (s+1) \dotsb (s+k)}
    \sum_{n=0}^{\ell-1} \frac{\frac{(k+1)\dotsb (k+n)}{n!} (-2\pi i \alpha)^n}{(s+k+1)\dotsb (s+k+n)} +  O\left( 
    \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{\binom{k}{j}\cdot (2\pi \alpha)^\ell}{
    |(s+j)\dotsb (s+j+\ell) |}\right),
\end{aligned}$$
and so, provided that $|\Im s| > |2\pi \alpha|$,
$$\mathscr{M} f(s) =  \frac{k! e(\alpha)}{s (s+1) \dotsb (s+k)}
    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{(k+1)\dotsb (k+n)}{n!} (-2\pi i \alpha)^n}{(s+k+1)\dotsb (s+k+n)}.$$
(This must be in some standard Mellin-transform grimoire I don't know of; reference?) We can thus bound
$$\begin{aligned}
|\mathscr{M} f(s)|&\leq \frac{k!}{|s (s+1)\dotsb (s+k)|}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)\dotsb (k+n)}{n!} \left(\frac{|2\pi \alpha|}{|\Im s|}\right)^n\\ &= \frac{k!}{|s (s+1)\dotsb (s+k)|} \left(1 - \frac{|2\pi \alpha|}{|\Im s|}\right)^{-(k+1)},\end{aligned}$$ assuming again that $|\Im s| > |2\pi \alpha|$.

Further questions:

(a) the inequality above has some slack; can one give a stronger closed-form estimate that is still simple and useful?

(b) it is of course possible to express $\mathscr{M} f$ as a linear combination of incomplete Gamma functions. Can one easily prove an inequality like the one above in that way?

Comment: Mathematica gives the result $$\int\limits_0^1 (1-x)^k\, e^{2 \pi i \alpha x}\, x^{s-1}\, dx=\Gamma(k+1)\, \Gamma(s)\, _1\tilde{F}_1(s;k+s+1;2 \pi i \alpha),\ \Re(k)>-1\land \Re(s)>0,$$ but I'm not sure it provides any insight.

Comment: @StevenClark I'm a bit confused about the tilde - what kind of hypergeometric function is that?

Comment: It's the Mathematica [Hypergeometric1F1Regularized function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1Regularized.html) which also links to [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and the [Wolfram functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1Regularized/).