# How fast can the Mellin transform of a twist $\eta(t) e(\alpha t)$ decay?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, integral-transforms

Let $\eta:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$. Consider the Mellin transform $F_{\alpha}$ of $\eta(x) e(\alpha x)$, and examine its behavior on a vertical line, such as $\Re s = 1/2$.

If $\alpha$ is close to $0$, then $F_{\alpha}(s)$ should behave roughly like $M\eta(s) = F_0(s)$. However, for larger $\alpha$, and $\mathrm{sgn}(\Im s) \ne \mathrm{sgn}(\alpha)$, the method of stationary phase gives us that $F_\delta(s)$ should have a term proportionate to $\eta\left(-\frac{\Im s}{2\pi \alpha}\right)$.

Now, if $\eta$ has compact support, that term will simply vanish for $-\frac{\Im s}{2\pi \alpha}$ larger than a constant. What will the dominant term in $F_\delta(s)$ then be for $\Re s$ fixed and $-\frac{\Im s}{2\pi \alpha}$ larger than a constant? Will it necessarily be proportional to $F_0(s)$? Or could it be smaller?

(See the related post [Mellin transform of $(1-x)^k 1_{[0,1]}(x) e(\alpha x)$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453908/mellin-transform-of-1-xk-1-0-1x-e-alpha-x) for an example: if $\eta(x) = (1-x)^k$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $\eta(x)=0$ for $x>1$, then $F_\delta(s)$ is in fact roughly of the order of $F_0(s) = M\eta(s)$ for $-\frac{\Im s}{2\pi \alpha}$ larger than $1$, with $F_\delta(s)$ getting closer to $F_0(s)$ as $- \frac{\Im s}{2\pi \alpha}$ increases.)

Comment: how exactly do you get the term in your fourth sentence? writing the oscillation part as $e(f(V))$ so that $f'(V)=0$ at $V\approx t/\alpha $ and so that $f''(V)\approx t/V^2$ i thought stationary phase gave us $\eta (t/\alpha ) V^{\sigma -1}/\sqrt {f''(V)}\approx \eta (t/\alpha )(t/\alpha )^{\sigma }/\sqrt t\approx \eta (t/\alpha )/\sqrt \alpha $. or am i doing something wrong there?